# How do I clone a 2 TB HDD onto a 120 GB HDD (shrink partition using gparted)

Tags: boot, partition, gparted, cloning, clonezilla

I have the following:

- Western Digital 2 TB HDD (65GB used space)
- Seagate 250 GB HDD (with nothing on it)

The 2 TB HDD has Mac OS X 10.6.8 that I need to clone onto the smaller drive in order to use it with a Mac Pro (A1186). I want to shrink the partition on the 2 TB drive via gparted and then use clonezilla to clone that partition along with the boot partition onto the 250 GB HDD. When I open gparted terminal shows an error that says it only supports 512 bytes length sector and gparted shows the partition with a caution exclamation mark that indicates it can not read the contents of the drive. Mounting the drive allows gparted to read the contents and tells me how much used/free space I have but I can't shrink the partition while its mounted. So how do I go about shrinking the partition ensuring both HDDs have the same byte sector size and cloning it to the other drive in order to make it bootable?

Please see images that show gparted with drive unmounted and with the drive mounted.

Terminal states: **"the sector sized stored in the journal is not 512 bytes. Parted only supports 512 bytes length sectors"**[image]
[image]

Comment: Please identify your images. (You have three images that appear to be photographs of the same screen, with only two descriptions.) Also, please post text as text.

Comment: sorry I didnt notice when I originally posted, hopefully it makes sense now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restore the drive with DiskUtility in Snow Leopard, no shrinking needed.

1. Erase the 250GB as "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive Journaled)" (or without "Case-sensitive")
2. Right-click "Restore" on the 2TB, choose source and destination (drag the partitions into the fields), click "Restore".
3. Finished

Comment: So format the 250 GB drive as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and within disk utility right click restore on the 2TB and choose the 250GB as destination and this clones the drive or reverts it back to factory settings? Will I also get all the data along with the OS and this will all result in a bootable drive?

Comment: This clones the content of the drive and it should be bootable.